# Doesn't appear div scrollbar Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

this example code work in Google Chrome and in IE, but doesn't work in Firefox.

The scrollbar correctly appear in Chrome and IE because the div **divScrollID2** is large *1200px* and the container, div **divScroll** is large just *700px*.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="divScroll" style=" background:green; overflow-y:hidden;width:700px;max-width:700px;min-width:700px;overflow-x:auto;height:14px;min-height:14px;max-height:14px;">
      <div style="background:pink; width:1200px;min-width:1200px;max-width:1200px;height:14px;min-height:14px;max-height:14px;" id="divScrollID2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

**Can anyone explain to me why in Firefox does not appear the scroll bar in divScrollID2 and how can I fix it?**

Thanks,

Tommaso

Comment: `width-min`, etc. should be `min-width`, etc.

Comment: yes, you've reason, I have write wrong... but the scrollbar does not appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your height restrictions are causing the problem. There's no room for a scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks!!!! If I remove height it work. But... how can I reduce to minimum height the div? ...I need to reduce the height of the "divs" because I wanna see just the scroll bar

Comment: @tommaso - What is the reason behind using two divs for this? If you just want to see a scroll bar - use one div and set the height to 21px. It you are worried about background colour then use `background-color : inherit`